# Possible reasons why my shadowsocks not working on virmach's server?

Tags: server

I'm a new comer to using the overseas server. Recently I bought a vps **from virmach** in order to see foreign websites like google and wiki.

I've been trying for a long time configuring my shadowsocks on my server.
However, when I was using shadowsocks-qt5 to connect my server, it was **timeout**.
And of course I can't access google correctly.

What I want to ask is the reason why I failed.
Here are things that I do remember to do:

1. **stop the firewall** on both computers;
2. **build the .json file** which I referred to blogs in China.

Here are the outline of my shadowsocks.json on my server:

> {
>        "server":"0.0.0.0",
>        "server_port":8388, 
>        "local_address":"127.0.0.1",
>        "local_port":1080, 
>        "password":"XXXX",
>        "timeout":600,
>        "method":"aes-256-cfb"
>   }

Other useful(maybe) information:

1. my client OS version: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
2. my server OS version: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
3. the client I choose is from: https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5

I could not help but wandered, are there any other possible reasons I've forgot? Can anyone inform me some helpful details to solve this puzzling problems? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have not set up my own VPS but I have instead subscribed to the server provided by caonima.io, so I can't speak for any server related issues. Additionally, I have no affiliation with caonima.io. I did however successfully set up my client on Ubuntu 16.04 after having some issues connecting to GFW-blocked (China's Great FireWall) websites.

From what I understand from my solution, the client configuration is NOT the only step of setup. There are two layers of proxy access that need to be completed:

1. **Client Configuration**. Configure your client with the server and connection information. A successful connection looked like this for me with my command line interface

[shadowsocks-libev command line client successful connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWOnc.png)

2. **System or Browser Proxy Configuration**. You will need to configure either your browser or web access tool to use a proxy, or set system-wide proxy settings. To set system wide proxy settings, go to `system settings > network > network proxy` and enter the proxy information. Setting `Socks host` to `localhost:1080` resulted in successful GFW-blocked website access (as shown below)!

[Ubuntu network settings proxy manual configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaLNT.png)